# dart test dart:html without loading dartium

Tags: dart

Is there any way to test a code with `dart:html` imported on it, without dartium being triggered.

I want to test `HttpRequest` to a JSON data and expected it to display it on terminal, and dart editor wants to open dartium EVERYTIME, which i think unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dartium contains the browser hosted Dart VM, which the relevant browser DOM bindings.  When you run code that needs a browser DOM, such as dart:html, you will get Dartium running.

However, you can also use DumpRenderTree - which is a headless browser (ie, produces output to the console).

Take a look at these post for more about DumpRenderTree and Dart:

- http://work.j832.com/2013/01/headless-browser-testing-dart.html
- http://docs.drone.io/dart.html
- http://japhr.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/regression-testing-of-browser-dart-code.html